# Is it possible to lock a file when the right to modify it is disabled?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio

I'm developing a desktop application. This app will be put in a server so that many users can run it. The app reads files from one folder of the server and eventually creates copies of them with some changes in another folder in the server. These files from the first folder are different accounting documents in their final form so we don't want users to change them. To avoid this problem we're thinking about disabling some rights for users such as the modify, the delete and the change right allowing to do other things like reading and creating.

In addition, there could be a situation when two or more users running the app would be trying to create the final changed copy of one file at the same time. For that situation the app locks the file for the first user and the second user can't access the file. He or she just goes to another file.

```
FileStream file = new FileStream(@"H:\" + doc_number + ".docx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
```

However, when the file is locked and the modify right is disabled, the exception arises while trying to lock a file. When the modify right is enabled, the exception doesn't arise, the second user don't have access to the file and the file is created by the first user, users can't delete and change files, they can only read, write, create and, of course, modify.

I don't understand why it's not working.

Comment: It's not clear how you're locking the file. Is it the `new FileStream()` code that you posted? In that case, then of course it fails because of the `FileAccess.ReadWrite`. It would need to be `FileAccess.Read`.

Answer (score 0):

According to your idea, if the user does not have the permission to modify, of course you will make an error when you use FileAccess.ReadWrite at this time.

Here you can add a judgment, if the file is locked and disable modification permission is to use FileAccess.Read. Otherwise use FileAccess.ReadWrite